# Inverse property with range restriction

Tags: owl, protege

In Protege, I have defined a class :Person, and an object property :likes (with domain :Person and range  :Person).

I have defined an inverse property of :likes called :isLikedBy.

Then I define an additional class :Rich.

I wish I could define a property :likesBackForBadReasons in this way: an equivalent property (or is it a subproperty?) of :isLikedBy, but only when the range of that relationship is an instance of :Rich.

So my inference engines infers that any :Rich :Person "A" who :likes a :Person "B", then this "B" :likesBackForBadReasons "A".

How to define that :likesBackForBadReasons object property in Protege?

Answer (score 0):

TL;TDR: This specific requirement can only be dealt with using rules and not by typical Description Logic (DL) inferences. You can use either of the following rules:

`Person(?x) ^ PersonThatIsNotRich(?x) ^ RichPerson(?y) ^ likes(?y, ?x) ^ likes(?x, ?y) -> BadPerson(?x)`

`Person(?x) ^ PersonThatIsNotRich(?x) ^ RichPerson(?y) ^ likes(?y, ?x) ^ likes(?x, ?y) -> likesForBadReason(?x, ?y)`

where `PersonThatIsNotRich` is disjoint with `RichPerson`. These rules also ensure that a rich person liking another rich person will not be considered a bad person.

**How to use SWRL to do this inference:**

The ontology using this rule in Manchester syntax is as follows:

```
ObjectProperty: isLikedBy
    InverseOf: likes
    
ObjectProperty: likes
    InverseOf: isLikedBy
    
ObjectProperty: likesForBadReason

    SubPropertyOf: likes        
    
Class: BadPerson
    SubClassOf: Person
    
Class: Person
    
Class: PersonThatIsNotRich
    SubClassOf: Person
    DisjointWith: RichPerson
    
    
Class: RichPerson
    SubClassOf: Person    
    DisjointWith: PersonThatIsNotRich
    
Individual: badPerson
    Types: Person
    Facts: likes  richPerson
    
Individual: otherBadPerson
    Types: Person
    Facts: likes  otherRichPerson
    
    
Individual: otherRichPerson
    Types: RichPerson
    Facts: likes  badPerson, likes  richPerson
    
Individual: richPerson
    Types: RichPerson
    
    Facts:  likes  badPerson, likes  otherRichPerson
   
Rule: 
    Person(?x), PersonThatIsNotRich(?x), RichPerson(?y), likes(?y, ?x), likes(?x, ?y) - BadPerson(?x)
```

Notes:

1. You will note that `badPerson` is inferred to be a `BadPerson` while `otherBadPerson` is not inferred to be a `BadPerson`. This is because `otherBadPerson likes otherRichPerson`, but `otherRichPerson likes badPerson`, not `otherBadPerson`. It is because the same rich person is not liked-back. It is the involvement of the same individual that causes a typical Description Logic reasoner to not be able to infer this correctly (or at least that is my understanding - someone who understands the difference between DL reasoners and rules better is welcome to correct me).
2. You will also note that a rich person liking another rich person and being liked back by that rich person, does not cause the rich person to be inferred to be a `BadPerson`.

**Why intuitive solution using DL axiom does not work:**

Intuitively one may think that defining `BadPerson` as follows will give the desired inference, but it does not:

```
Class: BadPerson
    EquivalentTo:
        (isLikedBy some RichPerson)
         and (likes some Person) and (not RichPerson)
        SubClassOf: Person
```

This will merely ensure that a `BadPerson` is liked by some rich person and that `BadPerson` likes some rich person, but the rich person is not necessarily the same rich person.

**Why define a `BadPerson` class rather than a `likesForBadReasons` property in DL?**

Reasoning in DL is defined in terms of classes and not in terms of relations. The basic reasoning in DL is classification and this aims to classify classes form the most general to the most specific. There is no such reasoning procedure for classification of relations.